# Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInitd7a72f88a86cf25d5563498a7179620e::getLoader()

Tags: laravel, composer-php, vagrant

Here is the message I have when I access my site:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInitd7a72f88a86cf25d5563498a7179620e::getLoader()
in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/autoload.php:7

Stack trace: #0 /home/vagrant/code/public/index.php(34): require() #1 {main} 
thrown in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
```

I am using

- popOS
- PHP 7.4.18
- Apache 2.4.41
- Vagrant 2.2.9
- Laravel 8.40.0

I have found many SO questions about it, but nothing worked so far. I tried:

- checked that the generated files are present and run (`dd`'d into it)
- `composer dump-autoload`
- `rm -rf vendor`, `composer install`
- changed PHP version (8.0.x, 7.4.18)
- deleted all caches (composer and Laravel)

If you have any idea on what's going on... Thanks!

**EDIT**

I destroyed the VM. Before anything else I accessed the site and had the message saying that the session table was not found. Good. Then I ran a `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` and here is the message I got:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Swift::registerAutoload() in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/vagrant/code/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(71): require() #1 /home/vagrant/code/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(61): composerRequiree92ff6905f8cf8863d20126d313557d0() #2 /home/vagrant/code/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInite92ff6905f8cf8863d20126d313557d0::getLoader() #3 /home/vagrant/code/public/index.php(34): require('/home/vagrant/c...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/vagrant/code/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php on line 13
```

It does not reappear after a refresh, but the first message popped again.

Comment: There was the github issue open related to this and the workaround for this was posted on https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1652#issuecomment-840642360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days on this issue I decided to switch from Homestead to Docker, though I've always worked with the first, and it worked well before I reinstalled my computer.

Now everything works well. This is not THE solution I was expecting, but I can now start to work again.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling opcache

In Ubuntu you can do this by adding

`opcache.enable=0`

to `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini`

Or for whatever PHP version you are running

**Edit:** you will also need to restart PHP with
`sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and ran optimize:clear and composer dump-autoload just to be sure, but I still have the same message :(

Comment: I had the same issue on a fresh Homestead install. I initially narrowed down my fix by restarting PHP with `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`. For the initial load everything would work, but subsequent loads I would get the same error as you did. Maybe try another version of PHP

Comment: I already tried this, as I initially was on PHP 8, but to no avail. I also tried to completely uninstall Composer and start a new Laravel app but I have the same message as soon as I run the site.